# React handleSubmit form - how to ensure that methods within the handlesubmit method will only be executed when a condition is satisfied

Tags: reactjs, forms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a search form that, when submitted, it triggers the handleSubmit() function and inside the handleSubmit() function I have I have 3 methods whose execution depends on each other, what I want is to ensure that each method is executed one by one inside the handleSubmit method

what I want is to ensure that the carregarCursos() method is only executed when the carregarDisciplinas() method is executed and that the carregarPlanoCurso() method is executed only when the carregarCurso() method is executed

```
function handleSubmit({
    anoLetivo1,
    curso1,
    unidadeCurricular1
  }) {

    carregarDisciplinas().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaDisciplina(
        value.filter((disciplina) => disciplina.nome === unidadeCurricular1)
      );
    });

    carregarCursos().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaCurso(value.filter((curso) => curso.nome === curso1));
    });

    carregarPlanoCurso().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaPlano(
        value.filter((plano) => plano.id_disci === resPesquisaDisciplina[0].id)
      );
    });

}
```

Below how the methods and variables are being declared:

```
  const [resPesquisaDisciplina, setResPesquisaDisciplina] = useState([]);
  const [resPesquisaCurso, setResPesquisaCurso] = useState([]);
  const [resPesquisaPlano, setResPesquisaPlano] = useState([]);
  async function carregarCursos() {
    const response = await api.get('cursos/');

    return response.data;
  }

async function carregarPlanoCurso() {
    const response = await api.get(`cursos/${resPesquisaCurso[0].id}/plano`);
    return response.data;
  }
async function carregarDisciplinas() {
    const response = await api.get('disciplinas/');

    return response.data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an async function and fetch all data you need, something like this:

```
async function loadAllData() {
    const cursos = await carregarCursos();
    const planos = await carregarPlanoCurso();
    const diciplinas = await carregarDisciplinas();
    return { cursos, planos, diciplinas }
}

loadAllData().then(({ cursos, planos, diciplinas }) => {
    //...All the setData functions 
});
```

Comment: this is brilliant i'll try now if it works i tell you...thanks so much for reply

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work because the problem is that inside the url of the request that the carregarPlanoCurso() method makes the api there is an id variable that will only be defined after the execution of the carregarCursos() method

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with `useEffect`, I made the `carregarPlanoCurso()` method be called only when the variable `resPesquisaCurso` changes size, `useEffect` was declared outside the scope of `handleSubmit`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (resPesquisaCurso.length !== 0) {
      carregarPlanoCurso().then((value) => {
        setResPesquisaPlano(
          value.filter(
            (plano) => plano.id_disci === resPesquisaDisciplina[0].id
          )
        );
      });
    }
  }, [resPesquisaCurso]);
```